# iOS5: How to set UIWindow subclass in UIStoryboard?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiwindow, uistoryboard

Since there seems to be no window settings in UIStoryboard editor, 
I want to know how to switch the AppDelegate's window class from UIWindow to its subclass.

What I often do is writing the following codes in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:,
but each time it really makes me dull.

```
UIViewController* vc = self.window.rootViewController;
self.window = [[MyWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = vc;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the right thing. That is the way to customize your window. Setting it in IB is just as cumbersome, if you think about it.

If you are dulled by the prospect of typing these three lines of code, consider the convenient  feature of the *Code Snippets Library* in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll try using Xcode's code snippet, but I really hope Apple to add method like -(Class)windowClass in UIApplicationDelegate's protocol:(